# Delphi component on mouse down function

Tags: delphi

I need to change component options by clicking on it but I need to implement this function for many objects that I create dynamically.

I need to do something like this:

```
Object_I_clicked_on.brush.color:= clred; ...
```

this is not good because there will be many components and all components will have the same function

BAD:    `shape1.brush.color:= clred;`

Is there some way to do this? Something with sender (variable) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new VCL project. Add a `TShape` to it. Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V so you get many of them on the form. Select them all and select the `OnMouseDown` event on the Events tab of the Object Inspector. Type `ShapeMouseDown` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then write

```
procedure TForm1.ShapeMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Sender is TShape then
    TShape(Sender).Brush.Color := clHighlight;
end;
```

If you have a lot of dynamically-created controls, the idea is the same. For instance, if you got an array `FShapes: array of TShapes` containing dynamically-created shapes, you need to give them all the same event handler:

```
for i := 0 to high(FShapes) do
  FShapes[i].OnMouseDown := ShapeMouseDown;
```